# zf2 transalator print msgid not translated text

Tags: php, zend-framework2, translate, po

I created the file it_IT.mo and it_IT.po that I placed in the folder

```
module/application/language/mydomain/
```

in file **module.php** I entered

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $eventManager->attach('dispatch.error', array($this,'onDispatchError'), 100);

    $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $translator->addTranslationFile(
        'phpArray',
        'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/it/Zend_Validate.php',
        'default',
        'it_IT'
    );
    $translator->addTranslationFilePattern('Gettext',"module/Application/language/mydomain/","mydomain");
    AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
}
```

in my **view**

```
<?php echo $this->translate("operation_allowed_false","ha","it_IT"); die();?>
```

operation_allowed_false is the msgid of the file

print the key and not the translated text

this is my file

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: ha\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-09-17 13:09+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2014-09-17 13:14+0100\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: it_IT\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.6.9\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: C:\\Users\\DEVELOPMENT\\xamp\\htdocs\\ha\\doc\\phpstring"
"\\contenuti\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: C:\\Users\\DEVELOPMENT\\xamp\\htdocs\\ha\\doc"
"\\phpstring\\contenuti\n"

#: C:\Users\DEVELOPMENT\xamp\htdocs\ha\doc\phpstring\contenuti/base.php:9
msgid "operation_allowed_false"
msgstr "Operazione non consentita."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Module.php** you register the gettext translationFilePattern with wrong a pattern. The pattern string must contain a "%s" which gets replaced by the locale string.

Example:

```
$translator->addTranslationFilePattern('gettext',"module/Application/language/mydomain","%s.mo");
```

So if your locale is it_IT, the translator will load the file *module/Application/language/mydomain/it_IT.mo*

---

In your **view** you want to translate from domain *ha* (second param):

```
<?php echo $this->translate("operation_allowed_false","ha","it_IT"); die();?>
```

But you did not register your translationFilePattern with a text domain. Set this parameter to `null` to use the default domain:

```
<?php echo $this->translate("operation_allowed_false" null,"it_IT"); die();?>
```

---

I would also recommend to move the translator configuration to your **module.config.php**:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'it_IT',
    'translation_files' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'phpArray',
            'filename' => '/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/it/Zend_Validate.php',
            'locale' => 'it_IT',
        ),
    ),
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language/mydomain',
            'pattern' => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

---

Everything untested

Comment: thanks it works! now i can translate my text. but when i set it on Module.php the messages of the validators were translated.

Comment: maybe i use 'AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator)'

Comment: Sorry, the config key was wrong. It must be `translation_files`, not `translation_file` (missing 's' at the end). Then it should work without setting the static default translator.