# Zend 2 Translation global

Tags: php, zend-framework2

The following code works fine in a controller,how global?

XXXController.php

```
$lang = 'nl';
$loc = $this->getServiceLocator();
$translator = $this->get('translator');
$translator->addTranslationFile("phparray",'./module/admin/language/lang.array.'.$lang.'.php');    
$loc->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('translate')->setTranslator($translator);
```

View.phtml

```
echo $this->translate('homepage');
```

The awnser:

module.config.php

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'it_IT',
    'translation_files' => array(
    array(
        'type' => 'phpArray',
        'filename' => './module/admin/language/lang.array.nl.php',

    ),
    ),
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
    array(
        'type' => 'gettext',
        'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language/mydomain',
        'pattern' => '%s.mo',
    ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set translator in your module config as in [Zend Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L60)

Comment: What and now? Thats all. When you setup translator just grab mvctranslator service from servicemanager and use it.

Comment: My question was how to do this global, so i want to set it once and use echo $this->translate('xxxx'); in every view. How can i do this?

Comment: if you have registered mvctranslator in module config, then its passed to translate view helper.

Comment: Ok, but how looks the code? Do you have an example?

Comment: I think we have misunderstood in configuration. just put to your module config: `return array(
    'translator' => array(
        'translation_files' => array(
            array(
                'type'        => 'phpArray',
                'filename'    => './module/admin/language/lang.array.nl.php',
                'locale'      => 'nl',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
`

Comment: Show me your config (pastebin, gist...)

Comment: This post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889545/zf2-transalator-print-msgid-not-translated-text Thnks!

Answer (score 0):

The awnser!

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'it_IT',
    'translation_files' => array(
    array(
        'type' => 'phpArray',
        'filename' => './module/admin/language/lang.array.nl.php',

    ),
    ),
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
    array(
        'type' => 'gettext',
        'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language/mydomain',
        'pattern' => '%s.mo',
    ),
    ),
),
```